# Vue Vite SPA application is not communicating with Laravel API GET http://localhost:5173/user/projects 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, axios, environment-variables, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to fetch a list from an endpoint but It throws error 404, It works from Postman but not inside the application. I created the .env file manually inside application root folder.

The error message shows `GET http://localhost:5173/user/projects 404 (Not Found)`

**.env:**

```
VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8000
VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH=/
```

**src/services/api.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const api = axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV.VUE_APP_API_URL });

export default api;
```

**vite.config.ts:**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import VueRouter from 'unplugin-vue-router/vite'
import { VueRouterAutoImports } from 'unplugin-vue-router'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite'
import { HeadlessUiResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    VueRouter({}),
    vue(),
    Components({ resolvers: [HeadlessUiResolver()] }),
    AutoImport({
      imports: ['vue', '@vueuse/head', VueRouterAutoImports],
    }),
  ],
  server: {
    open: true,
  },
})
```

**src/pages/Projects/index.vue:**

```
async function listProjects() {
  let projects = [];

    let projectsResponse = '';

    projectsResponse = await api.get('/user/projects');

    if (projectsResponse) {
      projects = projectsResponse.data.projects;
    }

    if (!projects || !projects.length) {
      projects = [];
      return;
    }

    projects = projects;
}
```

The endpoint is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/projects`, It works from postman (The backend is running locally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Vite, you should use `import.meta.env` instead of `process.env` to import environment variables. So you sould set the base url with: `baseURL: import.meta.env.VUE_APP_API_URL`.

See [Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html).

Answer (score 0):

`process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL` is what you need to access the env variable you've defined.

```
import axios from 'axios';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const api = axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL});

export default api;
```